# what is the time complexity for this recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
void solve(string op, int n, int zeros, int ones)
{
    if(n==0){
        cout<<op<<" ";
        return;
    }
    string op1 = op;
    op1.push_back('1');
    solve(op1, n-1, zeros, ones+1);
    if(ones > zeros){
        string op2 = op;
        op2.push_back('0');
        solve(op2, n-1, zeros+1, ones);
        return;
    }

}
```

what is the time complexity for the solve function? is it O(2^N)?  can someone please explain how you approach to find complexities for recursive functions?

link to question: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-n-bit-binary-numbers-1s-0s-prefixes/

Comment: You have to count how often the function is called and how much work is done in each of the (2 - multiple base/recursive) cases.

Answer (score 4):

So, we want to estimate the worse case here. The worse case would be if the condition (ones > zeros) always returns to true. Is it possible? Yes, if ones-zeros >= n. Since I don't know the context of your task, I may assume it.

Let T(n) is the complexity of your function. Your function calls itself with (n-1) two times. That means,

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-1) + c
```

where c is a constant for routines you are doing else like appending '1' or '0', condition evaluating etc. what is not depended on n.

So,

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + c =
     = 2(2T(n-2) + c) + c = 4T(n-2) + 3c = 
     = 4(2T(n-3) + c) + 3c = 8T(n-3) + 7c = 
     = ...
     = 2^k*T(n-k) + (2^k-1)*c
```

so if (n-k) == 0, you are done, as T(0) = z.  So, we are done when k == n. Regarding z it is not obvious. In the current implementation we do output a string which is O(n). If we would just count strings it would be O(1). If we printing is essential the final complexity would be O(n2^n) if not then O(2^n)

That means,

```
T(n) = z*2^n + (2^n - 1)*c = O(z2^n)
```

[UPDATE1]

after realizing the real problem which was not clear from the code snippet but became clear after reading the info from the provided link, I would say that the complexity is different.

The calculation above is still true under assumptions was made.

Now, to this problem. We want to find all sequences of 1 and 0 of length n where each prefix contains 1's not less than the number of 0's in this prefix.

The algorithm provides the solution to this problem. As you can notice at each recursive call, the algo adds either 0 or 1 to the resulting sequence. That means the number of recursive calls is exactly the umber of symbols in the resulting strings.

We know that the length of each resulting string is n. So, we need to figure out the number of strings. Let's take a look what your program finds for different n's:

```
n    | number of strings 
-----------------------
1    |    1
2    |    2
3    |    3
4    |    6
5    |    10
6    |    20
7    |    35
8    |    70
```

So, if you look carefully, you will recognize that these are binomial coefficients `C(n, n/2)`. This binomial coefficient can be estimated as `~2^n/(\pi * n/2)` by large `n`. So, the complexity of the algo is `O(2^n/(n))`. However, if we also consider printing at end of recursion, we need to multiply with n, as it is the length of the outputted string. So, we end up with O(2^n)

To be clean, we need to prove that our assumption is correct. Hopefully you can do it by induction or other methods.

[UPDATE2]

Your implementation suffers from coping the string at each iteration. This slows down the execution by factor n. You can avoid it by passing a reference to the string and removing the added character after a recursive call like this:

```
void solve(string &op, int n, int zeros, int ones)
{
    if(n==0){
        cout<<op<<" ";
        return;
    }
    op.push_back('1');
    solve(op, n-1, zeros, ones+1);
    op.pop_back();
    if(ones > zeros){
        op.push_back('0');
        solve(op, n-1, zeros+1, ones);
        op.pop_back();
        return;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Great answer but it made me curious also ,you said that you are unaware of the context but the question also has a links to a specific task (I assume that to solve the task we have to initially call the function with solve("",4,0,0); ) But then the behavior of the function is deterministic. In cases like that is it even relevant to talk about worst case scenarios or even big O notation ?Even in the case we just know we start with solve("",n,0,0). Can we take that in accordance to make an optimization on our estimation ?

Comment: The assumption that `c` is some constant we don't care about is not correct. The string is copied and its length depends on the parameters.

Comment: @AlexR: I didn't say that we should not care about `c`. In fact it is part of calculation. Your comment about coping a string is correct. Indeed it depends on `n` but it could be avoided by passing the reference to the string instead of copying it and by removing the added character right after the recursive call.

Comment: @SpyrosMourelatos: didn't notice the link. Was it there from very beginning? I read the question early morning and then let the window open for a while. After couple of hours I wrote the answer without updating the page. But maybe I just missed that. Sorry for that. If the context as described under the link, then it is different. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'm still not convinced that your analysis is entirely correct because even though you removed the copying, the string is still printed. Since `n` characters have to printed that should be an `O(n)` and not a constant operation. Now, I'm not sure if there are some C++ or OS optimizations that make printing short strings indeed constant, but if this was pseudo code, you surely would have to account for that. I think, what you calculated in your second update is not the `O` runtime but only a lower bound since it represents the absolute minimum of work we have to do.

Comment: @AlexR hum...okay, the printing is indeed not for free. In fact I didn't consider it as it as a part of algo. We could have just count such sequences. The algo steps would be the same. But you are right. I will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the time complexity for the function is O(N*2^N). I use the recursion tree to analyze the results.

Comment: can u please explain how its O(N*2^N)?